# Initialize Gensim LDA model with pre-determined topic distribution

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

Can we make gensim lda model to use pre-determined topic distribution, while determining topics for new docs?

Ex:

```
import gensim
texts=[['a','a','a'], ['b','b','b'],['c','c','c']]
d = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(texts)
bow = [d.doc2bow(doc) for doc in texts]
import numpy as np
user_topics=np.array([[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],[0,0,1]])
model = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus=bow, id2word=d, num_topics=3,  random_state=1,eta=user_topics)
model.get_topics()
```

Returns

```
array([[0.9728407 , 0.01204113, 0.01511812],
       [0.01140388, 0.9742677 , 0.01432837],
       [0.02468761, 0.00788806, 0.9674243 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Is it possible for `model.get_topics()` to return same distribution as 'eta'?

i.e.

```
[[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],[0,0,1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, because the prior (η) equals to the posterior (β) will only happen when the likelihood is a constant, and here the likelihood looks like a constant, i.e. each topic (in the prior) will only generate one word.

However, a practical issue is that we use log-likelihood in fitting LDA (See [algorithm 1](https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/mdhnips2010.pdf)), so the zeroes in the prior will be **smoothed out**. In addition, you may want to check other arguments in `gensim.models.LdaModel`, as many other thresholds are also involved during the implementation.

As a result, you will only see that β approaches, but not equals to η, and with more data (e.g. instead of 3 "a", try 300 "a"), it will be closer.